# After migrating to xcode 7 cocoa pods libraries stopped working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Recently new ios and xcode appeared so I decided to update to have a latest version. First of all migration manager popped out and left many syntax errors. But after one hour I fixed them all. App compiled and it was a disaster. I use several external libraries (written in objc) using cocoa pods. They mostly don't work now.

I'm using facebook image picker to get images from facebook - doesn't work, same for instagram image picker. As of my code also now ALAssets aren't working - well partially they are - I'm just not getting posterImages of groups and thumbnails of all photos. I can see correct amount of photos just thumbnails are all nils now.

There are more problems. Sometimes back button in navigation controller is not appearing. Anyone maybe I'd be able to fix that errors of 'my' code, but there's no way I'd fix all issues in these external libraries (especially in such a short time). I thought only swift will be impacted, but objc libraries are also under attack.

So is there an issue with some cocoa pods settings or just libraries will no longer work? I heard there's no way to use swift 1.2 in xcode 7. So I decided to downgrade back to 6.4. App compiled without any problem (after cleaning up derivedData). In simulator (ios 8.4) works like a charm. But on device with ios9 all the same issues are present. No photos thumbnails from gallery etc :)

Anyway there's one more thing. My app has to offer similar functionality to the one client has sent me few weeks ago. I may be unexperienced in ios programming, but this app isn't working as well! No photos from gallery :) And it's from appstore. It looked very professional. I smell serious changes under the ios 9 hood.

So I don't think it's something wrong with swift 2.0 - it's an ios itself.

Comment: As I didn't realize for the first time after downgrading to xcode to 6.4 on ios 9 device facebook and instagram are working. However as I said before no thumbnails from alassetslibrary and some back buttons are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed all the problems! I just want to say they were not related to migration from swift 1.2 to swift 2.0. Going one by one:

1. nil thumbnails from ALAssetsLibrary - not sure why this was happening, but I restarted device and problem never came back. So good advice is to check if they're not nil (as I did).
2. Not working instagram and facebook libraries. Well first of all there's nothing wrong with cocoa pods. Reason of all this mess is App Transport Security. I had to add this to Info.plist file (last one not related to facebook/instagram):

http://pastebin.com/rWgyiKXH

You simple have to add all servers that app connects.

3. Not working back button - well that was a problem with my storyboard. I had many push segues, but every viewController was embeedded in navigationController. That worked on ios8, but not on ios9. I had to get rid of them and left first one and ones that were appearing by replace segue.

No need to downgrade :)